# Prefect 2 Dask: submit Not Consuming Resources

Tags: python, dask, distributed-computing, distributed, prefect

**Goal:**
I am trying to Get tasks created by Prefect 2 for Dask to consume the GPU resource to prevent over working.

**Checked:**
I setup my dask-workers with a resource of GPU=1 each. I have checked the dashboard and confirmed they all have GPU as 1.

**Problem:**
When running my task via Prefect 2 I don’t see the resource being marked as consumed and then eventually each worker gets over worked and crashes.

This is what I am doing in prefect from my understand of the documentation in https://prefecthq.github.io/prefect-dask/:

```
import requests
from prefect import flow, task, get_run_logger
from prefect_dask.task_runners import DaskTaskRunner
import dask

@task
def UpscaleFrames(FramesToUpscale):
    # Do some work with CUDA
    return

@flow(task_runner=DaskTaskRunner(address="tcp://tower:8786"))
def Upscale():
    for file in GetVideoFiles("/videos"):
        while (frames_found):
            FramesToUpscale = GetFramesToUpscale()
            with dask.annotate(resources={'GPU': 1}):
                    UpscaleFrames.submit(FramesToUpscale)
```

**Version Info**:

```
Version:             2.3.2
API version:         0.8.0
Python version:      3.10.6
Git commit:          6e931ee9
Built:               Tue, Sep 6, 2022 12:36 PM
OS/Arch:             linux/x86_64
Profile:             default
Server type:         hosted
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a full example of your flow to see how you apply that?  Also, what is your Prefect version? Printing the output of `prefect version` would be helpful.

If you run on self-hosted Orion, the likely problem is networking -- this is something that would be easier to set up for a PoC with Cloud (there is a free tier so you can just sign up to troubleshoot: https://app.prefect.cloud/).

If nothing else works, it might help to create a GitHub issue on the Collection repo https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect-dask/issues describing all the steps you've taken so far and what doesn't work as expected

Comment: I added the version and to the pseudo code.